# How to search a list that contains specific dynamic values

Tags: java, android

I have a list of type `Model_BarcodeDetail` which conatins attributes like `barcode, area,location,color` etc. 
when I enter any barcode in the edittext, I want to search that barcode in the list(**list can have n number of similar barcodes** with similar area and location or different area and location), if the barcode I entered and the similar barcode that is presnt in my list have same area and location then I want to `doSomething()` else `doSomethingElse()`.

The code I tried is:

```
private List<String> barcodeList = new ArrayList<String>();
barcode = editText_barcode.getText().toString().trim();
if ((scanned_barcode != null
            && scanned_barcode.equalsIgnoreCase(barcode))) {
        if ((!barcodeList.contains(barcode)) ) {

 // if barcode I entered does not contains in the list
//  It is working fine
barcodeList.add(barcode);//barcodeList contains only barcode

        }
 else if (barcodeList.contains(barcode) ) {

            data = list.get(barcodeList.indexOf(barcode));
  // here is the problem
  // here I want to get data of the barcode that have similar area and   
     location 
            if (data.getArea() == selected_area
                    && data.getLocation() == selected_loc) {

            doSomething();
} else {
                doSomethingElse();
            }

        }
```

Comment: what is datatype of `barcodeList`

Comment: I dont really know what you want. You want to search and show to your listview or just search with `for` loop?

Answer (score 1):

Search your string in array list and get Object and then check location of barcode, here is sample code:

```
    barcode = editText_barcode.getText().toString().trim();
            if ((scanned_barcode != null
                && scanned_barcode.equalsIgnoreCase(barcode))) {
            Model_BarcodeDetail model_barcodeDetail=getBarcodeDetails(barcode);
// for handling array do this in loop 
            if (model_barcodeDetail!=null && model_barcodeDetail.getArea() == selected_area && model_barcodeDetail.getLocation() == selected_loc) {
                doSomething();
            }else{
                doSomethingElse();
            }
        }

/* your list can contain n number of similar bar code then change return type of this function to Model_BarcodeDetail[] */
    private Model_BarcodeDetail getBarcodeDetails(Sttring barcode){

        for (Model_BarcodeDetail model_barcodeDetail : list) {
            if (barcode.eqauals(model_barcodeDetail.getBarcode)){
                return model_barcodeDetail;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks it helped me.. :)

Answer (score 0):

When your list looks something like:

`List<Model_BarcodeDetail> list = new ArrayList<Model_BarcodeDetail>()`

you can use an foreach loop:

```
        barcode = editText_barcode.getText().toString().trim();
        if ((scanned_barcode != null
            && scanned_barcode.equalsIgnoreCase(barcode))) {
        if ((!barcodeList.contains(barcode))) {

            // if barcode I entered does not contains in the list
            //  It is working fine
        }

        for (Model_BarcodeDetail model_barcodeDetail : list) {
            if (model_barcodeDetail.getArea() == selected_area && model_barcodeDetail.getLocation() == selected_loc) {
                doSomething();
                break;
            }
        }

        // Nothing found
        doSomethingElse();

    }
```